# Google Charts not showing data

Tags: javascript, django, google-visualization

I have this template:

```
{% block header %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div align="center" style="margin-top:35px;"><a href="/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back to latest</button></a></div>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"  style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"><div>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Currency', 'Rate', { role: 'style' }],
    ['USD', parseFloat({{rates.0}}), 'gold'],
    ['GBP', parseFloat({{rates.1}}), 'silver'],
    ['HKD', parseFloat({{rates.2}}), 'brown'],
    ['AUD', parseFloat({{rates.3}}), 'blue'],
    ['SEK', parseFloat({{rates.1}}), 'red'],
    ['JPY', parseFloat({{rates.2}}), 'yellow'],
    ['NOK', parseFloat({{rates.3}}), 'orange'],
    ['EUR', parseFloat({{rates.3}}), 'orange'],
  ]);



  var options = {
    title: 'Exchange rate overview',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: ''
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
//]]>  

</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Right now, it shows me this:

What's wrong with it? It should show some bars with data, any ideas?

The json data is actually being feteched by the way, it's from a Django application.

If You need further explanation, please let me know.

[image: No data shown]

Comment: This was originally like this: {{rates[0]}}, but first, had to change it to {{rates.0}}, because of the python framework convention, this was a project I was migrating from one framework to another, then from your suggestion, I've changed it to parseFloat({{rates.0}}) , now it's working, kinda, but doesn't show any data on it

Comment: right, trying to find out the result of the statement, does it produce a number? you should be able to right click the page in the browser and view the page source to see the result.

Comment: Seems like there is nothing, duh, I'm puzzled, let me check the original one

Comment: Okay, the original one, shows the actual values on source, the result, this one just says ´parseFloat()´ instead of the result

Comment: This is an actual result number: 1.145357, it is a Float actually